# Como puedo Remover o borrar un preventDefault desde el input

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un input que valida si un codigo es valido o no y devuelvo un mensaje de error el problema que tengo es que el botón hace un refresh del envió y se aprecia mis mensajes pero solo unos segundos y se borra, le coloque un eventpreventDefault() al botón que envía y con eso logro ya que no refresque el envió y aprecio el mensaje, per o ahora me pasa que al borrar el input o al empezara borrar lo escrito en el input no puedo remover los mensajes mostrados, alguna idea, muchas Gracias por su apoyo, dejo los códigos que he avanzado, esta echo en angular: y una imagen.

--- ACTUALIZACION SOLUCION DE MI PARTE A MI PROBLEMA ----

Hice una actualización y ya casi lo tengo solo tengo el problema que al enviar o al submit el input queda marcado, con le mensaje me gustaría que al enviar quede en su estado Incial, no se como podría remover probé con un forma.reset(); pero no me resulta, su apoyo gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
public applyCupon() {
  this.isValidatingCupon = true;
  const cupons = this.discountCodeTags.map(tag => tag.code);
  const currentCupon = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
  if (!cupons.includes(currentCupon)) {
    const params = {
      coupon: this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value
    } as IDiscountCodeRequestParams;
    this.discountCodeImplement.validateDiscountCode$(params)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(response => {
        if (response.valid) {
            const couponInput = new Coupon ();
            couponInput.barCode = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
            couponInput.productName = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
            this.addCoupons.push(couponInput);
            this.guardarLocalStorage();
            this.discountCodeForm.resetForm; // esta linea es la que invoco desde el otro archivo
        } else {
          this.errorScheduleModalService.showErrorCouponModa(currentCupon);
        }
        this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.setValue('');
        this.isValidatingCupon = false;
      });
  } else {
    this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.setValue('');
  }
```

```html
<form
      [formGroup]="discountCodeForm.form"
      (ngSubmit)="applyCupon()"
      [hidden]="discountCodeTags.length > 0"
      class="block_codigo_descuento"
    >
      <div class="input_codigo_descuento">
        <fp-input-control
          [inputTitle]="''"
          [errorMessage]="''"
          [marginBottomZero]="true"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            id="nameCupon"
            class="input"
            placeholder="Ej. 6W79H6"
            formControlName="code"
            [class.isinvalid]="!discountCodeForm.form.valid && discountCodeForm.form.touched"
          />
          <small class="small" *ngIf="!discountCodeForm.form.valid && discountCodeForm.form.touched">
            Código Inválido
          </small>
        </fp-input-control>
      </div>
      <div class="btn_agregar_codigo">
        <button
          type="submit"
          id="applyCoupon"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-aplicar"
          [disabled]="!discountCodeForm.form.valid || isValidatingCupon"
        >
          Agregar
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

En este componente adicional es donde se controla el form y en le cual le pase reset form y ese reset lo invoco con un getter en el otro archivo el cual se coloca en la parte de la validación como todo es ok, envía y hace el reset y vuelve a su estado original,

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DiscountCodeControl } from '../controls/discount-code-control';

@Injectable()
export class CheckoutDiscountCodeFormService {

  public form: FormGroup;

  private _discountCode = new DiscountCodeControl();

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      code: this._discountCode,
      
    });


  }

  public get resetForm() {
    return this.form.reset();
  }

  public get codeControl() {
    return this.form.get('code') as DiscountCodeControl;
  }
}
```